# Owl Carousel 2 and Featherlight.js – mouseDrag causes opening of the lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, featherlight.js

In a project I am using [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/) in combination with [featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/).
In Owl Carousel it you have the possibility to activate "mouseDrag" so you can drag the carousel with your mouse. This works fine! Also when I have real hyperlinks inside a slide it does not open them when dragging.

But with featherlight it is different. If I have **featherlight-links inside a slide it will open them when I drag the carousel**. Why is it like this? Can I somehow correct this behavior?

**I made a code example which demonstrates the problem:**
(please drag the two carousels)

https://codepen.io/xj6652/pen/OJNPOqj

While dragging the carousel it will open the lightbox:

```
<div class="owl-carousel featherlightlinks">
  <div> 
    <a href="#" data-featherlight="#content" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  …
</div>
```

But with normal links inside a slide this does not happen:

```
<div class="owl-carousel reallinks">
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  …
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `changed.owl.carousel` event to prevent the triggering of the link using `beforeOpen` in `featherlight` with the help of a global variable (`followFeatherlightlink` in the code below). To do this, you need to prevent the automatic binding of elements with the attribute `data-featherlight`. You can do it in several ways, I just eliminated the attribute. In theory, you might also set `$.featherlight.autoBind` to `false` before the DOM loads, but I have not tried. I am showing the code below, but it does not seem to work properly. However, it works on [codepen](https://codepen.io/vqf/pen/QWNwraY)

```js
let followFeatherlightlink = true;
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  margin:10,
  loop:true,
  dots: false,
  nav: false,
  items: 3
});
$(".owl-carousel").on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  followFeatherlightlink = false;
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.featherlightlinks .blocklink').featherlight('#content', {
  beforeOpen: function(event){
  let result = followFeatherlightlink;
  followFeatherlightlink = true;
    return result; 
}
});
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel div{
  position: relative;
}

.owl-item {
  background-color: #D2527F;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

a.blocklink{
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.reallinks a.blocklink{
  background: green;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

h2:nth-of-type(2){
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/featherlight/1.7.13/featherlight.min.js"></script>
<h2>Problem: Dragging causes open lightbox</h2>
<div class="owl-carousel featherlightlinks">
  <div> 
    <a href="#" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="#"  class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="#"  class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="#"  class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="hidden">
  <div id="content">My Lightbox Content</div>
</div>


<h2>With real links it is working</h2>
<div class="owl-carousel reallinks">
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <a href="http://codepen.io" class="blocklink"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```